# Extract local maximum from FFT frame after processing with spectrogram using matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, spectrogram

I want to extract local maximum from FFT frame after processing signal with spectrogram.

Specifically, said that I have a audio file which is a `wav` file and it's collected in the following procedure:

phone user hold the smartphone at approximately arm's length, breathe in their full lung volume, and forcefully exhale until the entire lung volume is expelled. The phone's microphone records the exhalation and store data in a wav file.

Then i process the audio with spectrogram using following procedure:

Firstly, I buffer the audio into 30ms frames (with 50% overlap between frames). Then each frame is windowed using a hamming window and the `|FFT|db` is taken to produce the magnitude spectrogram of the signal.

Here is how i do that using matlab:

```
 [X, FS] = audioread('Rec_002.wav');
 info = audioinfo('Rec_002.wav');
 window = (30*0.001/info.Duration)*info.TotalSamples;
 [s,f,t,ps]=spectrogram(X, window, [], [], FS);
```

Rec_002.wav is my audio file. After processing signal with spectrogram, i want to extract the resonances using local maximum in each frame, calculated over a sliding window. Then, any local maximum that is greater than 20% of the global maximum is saved.

Below shows how spectrogram looks like when using the data above:
[Spectrogram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnfGB.png)

This shows what resonances should looks like after extracting from spectrogram

[After extracting resonaces from spectrogram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIZDw.png)

By now, I use one of output argument `s` - Short-time Fourier transform to extract local maximum.

Here's my code:

```
 local_max=max(abs(s));
 threshold=0.2*max(local_max,[],2); 
 local_max=local(:,local_max>threashold);
```

The questions is that I am not sure whether it's correct to use `s` or should i use `ps` - Power spectral density (PSD) to achieve my goal.

Can anyone point out to me? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spectrogram's output, *s*, is the amplitude of the frequency component in your signal between [*t1, t2*].

Power Spectral density, can be used to calculate the amount of power within a frequency range for the given time duration (STFT) through summation (integration if CT domain). This is somewhat intuitive from the name, "density".

So if you apply the threshold logic to *ps* instead of *s*, you will end up with highest gradient (local) instead of maximum (local).

Comment: So do you mean if i use `ps`, i am extracting highest gradient. To extract local maximum, i have to use `s` instead. By the way, does extracting local maximum have any special meaning in the context of spectrogram processing. Because i read it from a paper, and i am trying to understand why the author want to extract local maximum

Comment: Also, i have updated my question, so if you have a free time, can you have a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: The reason you are using spectrogram, which is short-time FT is that the input signal is non-stationary, ie, the frequency content is changing with time. So if you are interested in finding out the resonant frequency, i.e, frequency with the largest amplitude, during each time window, you need the local maximum of S.

Comment: Ok, I get it. By the way, can you tell me what does this `|FFT|db` mean?

Comment: It simply means magnitude of FFT in dB

Comment: If you don't mind can you share the link to this paper. I am curious.

Comment: yeah, That's totally fine. [SpiroSmart: Using a Microphone to Measure
Lung Function on a Mobile Phone](http://ubicomplab.cs.washington.edu/pdfs/spirosmart.pdf). Here is the link to that paper. By now, I am working on `spectrogram processing` section, But i am stuck in it. So if you find anything helpful, could you let me know? Thanks!